# Group color shadows to its base color c#

Tags: c#, colors

I want to classify image pixel color to one basic color 
for example
{ Dim-gray, light-gray , silver }there base color is ====> "Gray"
{Medium blue    ,Midnight blue  ,Navy blue}  ===>"blue"
and so on

Comment: You may want to look into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx Have a look at doing this approach and come back with any problems

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use `C#`s [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) structure, you can do something like the following with the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
Dictionary<Color, List<Color>> colorDict = new Dictionary<Color, List<Color>>();
colorDict.Add(Colors.Gray, new List<Color>() { Colors.DimGrey, Colors.Silver });
colorDict.Add(Colors.Blue, new List<Color>() { Colors.LightBlue, Colors.MidnightBlue });
```

You would then have a method to find the `Key` colour for each colour passed in, like so:

```
private Color FindKeyColour(Dictionary<Color, List<Color>> dict, Color c)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        //The colour is not a key
        return dict.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Value.Contains(c)).Key;
    }
    else
    {
        //The colour passed in is a key
        return c;
    }
}
```

Note: This function will need modifying if the Color `c` is not a Key or contained within a value.